# Cannot run Sync command externally (curl) for Airbyte

Tags: docker, localhost, airbyte

I want to Trigger a sync operation on Airbyte (Hosted on Docker) externally and below is the CURL command I am trying to run.
 `curl -u 'airbyte:password' -X POST "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/connections/sync" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"connectionId":"[XXXXXXX8b-1b35-4XXe-9XXX3-e06b5XXXXd04]"}'`

and it gives below error:

`curl: (28) Failed to connect to IPADDRESS port 8001 after 133762 ms: Couldn't connect to server.`

I was trying to implement this as per this article by [Airbyte](https://airbyte.com/tutorials/how-to-use-airflow-and-airbyte-together)

Instead of using localhost in curl command i have tried and replaced it with actual IP of below:

1. wsl hostname -I
2. or IP address showing against o/p of *docker inspect $(docker ps -q) --format='{{ .Name }} {{ .Config.Image }} {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}} {{.IPAddress}} {{end}}'* and choosing IP shown against airbyte/server row.
3. or just trying with host.docker.internal

but it's not working either way.

Answer (score 0):

You use the outdated version. The url should be http://localhost:8006/v1/jobs, then provide connectionId and jobType in params.

```
curl -u 'airbyte:password' --request POST \
     --url http://localhost:8006/v1/jobs \
     --header 'accept: application/json' \
     --header 'content-type: application/json' \
     --data '{"connectionId":"XXXXXXX8b-1b35-4XXe-9XXX3-e06b5XXXXd04","jobType":"sync"}'
```

You could see updated documentation here: https://reference.airbyte.com/reference/createjob

Comment: I haven't tested it yet - will try it in evening but i think you are spot on correct - because on a slack community someone mentioned to me that  Airbyte API is exposed on 8006 port , so what you mentioned make sense, will try it in the eveni g and mark your question as correct :)

Comment: Yeah, the tutorial you followed is just an article, so it can be outdated. Always check lastest guide from official documentation :))